# Not able to store the multi-index csv file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like ,

```
                         JAPE_feature                     
                     100 200 2200 2600 4600         
did offset word                                                               
0   0      aa          0   1    0    0    0          
0   11     bf          0   1    0    0    0           
0   12     vf          0   1    0    0    0             
0   13     rw          1   0    0    0    0             
0   14     asd         1   0    0    0    0               
0   16     dsdd        0   0    1    0    0               
0   18     wd          0   0    0    1    0              
0   20     wsw         0   0    0    1    0               
0   21     sd          0   0    0    0    1
```

Now, Here I am trying to save this dataframe in a csv format.

```
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

SO, it gets stored like,

[image]

Now, Here I am trying to save without creating the new columns in the JAPE_feature column. it would have the 5 sub features in one column only.

```
         JAPE_FEATURES
   100 |  200 |  2200 |   2600 | 4600 

the sub-columns should be like this . It should not create the different columns
```

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: I will just add that ,.. it will not have the diff columns . So, JAPE_feature will be the first column but the sub columns should be there in the same column

Comment: what is reason for save this way? Because I think you can do it only in excel `df.to_excel('data.xlsx')`, in csv by default it is not possible.

Comment: okay.. I will try to do in that way..   using the xlsx format. then will check again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here the best is convert DataFrame to excel, if need `merge` first level of `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

---

If want `csv` then it is problem, is necessary change `MultiIndex` for repalce duplicated values to empty strings:

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('JAPE_feature',  100),
            ('JAPE_feature',  200),
            ('JAPE_feature', 2200),
            ('JAPE_feature', 2600),
            ('JAPE_feature', 4600)],
           )

cols = df.columns.to_frame()
cols[0] = cols[0].mask(cols[0].duplicated(), '')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([cols[0], cols[1]])
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('JAPE_feature',  100),
            (            '',  200),
            (            '', 2200),
            (            '', 2600),
            (            '', 4600)],
           names=[0, 1])

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Great answer @jezrael.. As always :-)